# PHP login page security audit

Tags: php, security, authentication

I am doing a security audit on my login logic and trying to figure out which password check is more secure, and the better algorithm. Below are the two methods in pseudo PHP code:

Method I:

```
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
$password_hash = $bcrypt->hash($_POST['password']);
$result = mysqli_query_check_login($username, $password_hash);

if(mysqli_numb_rows($result) > 0) {
   //is valid
}
```

Method II:

```
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
$result = mysqli_query_check_login($username);

//Note $result->password is a bcrypt hash
if($bcrypt->verify($_POST['password'], $result->password)) {
   //is valid
}
```

The difference is `method I` runs bcrypt hash and then sends the username and hashed password in the mysql query. `Method II` gets the hashed password from mysql via the username only and then in PHP compares the two values.

Is there any security difference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are effectively the same thing. There should be no security implications in using either method.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Method II` would probably make it simpler to get the user's information and update something like a "failed login attempts" counter. Most implementations I've seen for `Method I` simply rely on `WHERE user=$login AND password=$password` not selecting the user if the password doesn't match.